# Export data from Multi-Line Long text field

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a field that is long text for Address. The prev users had put data into the field with carriage returns, so the address field [AddressForLtr] currently looks like this on a form:

John Doe
Acme Corp
123 Main Street
Your Town, MO, 12345

I would like to run an update query that will grab each line and put it into separate address fields but it's been a while since I've used the Left([AddressForLtr]) type code to grab data.

The new fields ([Address001], [Address002], etc) are in the same table as the singular address field [AddressForLtr]

Thanks in advance for your help or direction.

Comment: You have VBA tagged, so assuming you want to do it in VBA, you can use the `Split` function with the carriage return as the delimiter.

Comment: How do I refer to the carriage return in vba? (as opposed to " " for spaces or "," for delimiter? 

Would it be "Chr(13) or "vbCrLf"

Comment: Both should work, it kinda depends on how they were input. You can just try each one and figure out which one works for you, right? (note: those should not be in quotes, but you probably know that) 13=carriage return, 10=line feed - `vbCrLf` is both

Answer (score 1):

Build VBA function to parse data. If there are always 4 lines in data and always separated by Cr and Lf, a simple function using Split() might suffice.

```
Function GetAddPart(intP As Integer, strS AS String) As String
GetAddPart = Split(strS, vbCrLf)(intP)
End Function
```

Call the function in a query or textbox. So in a VBA UPDATE action, like:
`CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE table Set Address001=GetAddPart(0, AddressForLtr), Address002=GetAddPart(1, AddressForLtr), Address003=GetAddPart(2, AddressForLtr), Address004=GetAddPart(3, AddressForLtr)"`

To also parse city/state/zip (really should be in separate fields), again making assumptions all 3 parts exist and separated by comma, modify function:

```
Function GetAddPart(intP As Integer, strS As String, Optional strC As String = vbCrLf) As String
GetAddPart = LTrim(Split(strS, strC)(intP))
End Function
```

Call function:
`CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE table Set Address001=GetAddPart(0, AddressForLtr), Address002=GetAddPart(1, AddressForLtr), Address003=GetAddPart(2, AddressForLtr), Address004=GetAddPart(3, AddressForLtr), City=GetAddPart(0, GetAddPart(3, AddressForLtr), ",")"`etc

Consistency of structure is critical in string manipulation. If any elements, such as company name, are missing, this code will not save data correctly. It can be virtually impossible to programmatically parse data with confidence if structure varies.

Advise to use more descriptive field names than Address001, such as CustName, Company, Street. BTW, people name parts should also really be in separate fields, such as FName, MName, LName, Title, Suffix.

Comment: Note that Split() returns a zero-based array, so the first one is (0).

Comment: Ooops, adjusted answer.